# Multiple exit points from a Task (immediate and delayed)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I'm trying to concatenate the functionality of two separate functions in to a single Task. I'm probably being pedantic but I was also intrigued to see if this was possible so hopefully some C# wizard out there has the answer.

This is the current setup.

```
async Task GetData()
{
    // Get some cached data immediately from the database
    Data = FetchDataLocal(); 

    // Replace the local data with the data from the web when it is available 
    Data = await FetchDataRemote();
}
```

I'd like to move both these functions in to a single Task that just returns `Data` but of course a task can only return once.

So essentially I need this (below) sort of functionality but in the correct form. I'm optimistic there's an elegant solution out there.

```
async Task<DataType> GetData()
{
    // Get some cached data immediately from the database
    return FetchDataLocal(); 

    // Replace the local data with the data from the web when it is available 
    return await FetchDataRemote();
}
```

Is there some sort of Task solution that allows you to do something like this? So the Task would return data twice (the immediate data then the delayed data). The solution probably isn't even a Task but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: How would the calling code look like?

Comment: A single Task function in a service class called ReportService that only cares about getting an object of type Report. I would like it to immediately return the local report and then when the web fetch returns it would return the new report from the web data. The Task function is part of a chain of Tasks in service classes that is launched from an ICommand which comes from a UI project Xamarin.IOS, this fires off when a view is entered. I am databinding to the Report property in a view model. Which is where the ICommand is located also. All built on MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're working in an MVVM application, I'd recommend using [my `NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async), which handles the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff for you:

```
public NotifyTask<TData> Data;

ViewModelConstructor()
{
  // Get some cached data immediately from the database
  var immediateData = FetchDataLocal(); 

  // Replace the local data with the data from the web when it is available
  Data = NotifyTask.Create(FetchDataRemote(), immediateData);
}
```

If you do use `NotifyTask<T>`, then you'll need to data-bind to `Data.Result`.

Comment: I am working in an MVVM application. Great I'll give that a go.

Comment: Hi Stephen I've implemented NotifyTask, I'm trying to return Data.Result (where Data is the NotifyTask object). Then assign that to a property in my view model (that implements the MvvmCross version of RaisePropertyChanged). When NotifyProperties is called in NotifyTask propertyChanged event is null. How do I hook that up the MvvmCross property in the view model? Bit of a vague question sorry.

Comment: `NotifyTask` is designed to be data-bound to directly. If you want to "propagate" the result, you'll need to hook up to `((INotifyPropertyChanged)NotifyTask).PropertyChanged` and set your own property from there.

Comment: I had a feeling you were gona say that :) Great so that will call the setter on the property in the ViewModel which will raise it's own property changed event and that will propagate down to the UI. Okay I'll try and think of a nice way to wrap it all up neatly. Thank you. p.s. I'll use TestUtils.PropertyNotified as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that holds both objects and rases a event when it was updated.

```
public class DeferredData<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DeferredData(T cachedData, Task<T> dataFactory)
    {
        _data = cachedData;
        DatabaseLookupTask = dataFactory.ContinueWith(task => Data = task.Result, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private T _data;

    public T Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        private set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _data)) return;
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Task DatabaseLookupTask { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

used like

```
    DeferredData<DataType> GetData()
    {
        // Get some cached data immediately from the database
        var localData = FetchDataLocal();

        // Replace the local data with the data from the web when it is available 
        var remoteTask = FetchDataRemote();

        return new DeferredData<DataType>(localData, remoteTask);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, testing your code right now. I'm using .NET 4.5 due to the restrictions of the platform, `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` is a feature of .NET 4.6 is there any workaround for that? Cheers.

Comment: It should be fine without it